# Is it possible to change gettext files from PHP?

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

We're developing a multi-language website and in case of changes to the original text (English) they shouldn't appear on the site until all of the localized entries are changed accordingly. I don't think that's possible to do with `gettext`/POEdit alone (?). Another thing is concurrency of translation. If a bunch of people would edit the same `gettext` files on their PCs and then upload the changes to SVN, the situation when some translations were done by many people is inevitable.

Therefore it seems to be a good idea to store changed phrases in the database and once every language has its translation, make changes to po/mo files so that there is at every moment just actual information on the site.

Is it possible to make changes to gettext translation files with PHP? If not, should we forsake gettext in lieu of storing everything in the database?

Thanks

Comment: There is currently a nice comprehensive list of [gettext online editors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401307/how-can-using-gettext-help-me-here/4421846#4421846) in bountyland. As for the enable-if-fully-translated feature, a simple check-all or manual status flag might suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've tried a bunch of stuff and it seems that [PEAR File/Gettext](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Gettext/redirected) is the way to go. I seems to be kind of abandoned and files, created by POEdit and File/Gettext aren't binary similar, but I've checked the differences and they are mostly in metadata (which isn't needed for the proper functioning either way), except the hashtable, which isn't handled in the PHP package, but the docs for the `mo` state that the hashtable isn't required either and it's questionable whether is must be contained in those files :)

Comment: I just came accross these files today, I can't figure out exactly what there are for or how to use them, did you have any luck?  I know there have something to do with .po and .mo files which is what I was looking for, a way to work with them in PHP

Comment: @jasondavis, I'm able to happily compile/decompile po/mo from PHP, please make a question and specify your problem