# PHP Sanitized markdown - html output

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string, wmd-editor, wmd-markdown

I have WMD editor on my site, and i store the markdown in the DB. But before i send the markdown to database i filter it with mysql_real_escape_string, like that:

```
$to_database = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['markdown']);
```

And it's okay. But now I want to show it, so i use PHP Markdown (which converts markdown to html). But the problem is that it shows me **\r\n** and **\n** instead of new lines. I tried nl2br function, but it didn't help. Even if I do not escape the output (do not convert markdown to html and using htmlpurifier) I still get \n instead of new lines. 
Only when I remove mysql_real_escape_string it looks fine.

bbbbbbbbbbb
nnnnnnnnn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

They are being converted and are no longer acting as line breaks.  You want to replace them:

```
$markdown = str_replace('\r\n','<br/>',$_POST['markdown']);
$markdown = str_replace('\n','<br/>',$markdown);
```

You might also want to do this:

```
$markdown = html_entity_decode($markdown);
```

Comment: Thanks, however it shows me <br/> in the text (it's &lt;br/&gt; in source code). PHP Markdown somehow converts <br /> to html entities i guess (because when i've removed the php markdown processing i got the line breaks ok).

Comment: str_replace accepts arrays, you can do it in one function call: `str_replace(array('\r\n','\n'), '<br />', $_POST['markdown'])`

Answer (score 0):

You may have something sitting on your input layer and escaping incoming characters with backslashes, so that when you use `mysql_real_escape_string` you're actually getting double-escaped content.

If you are very unlucky that thing might be `magic_quotes_gpc` in which case you should [get rid of it](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php) ASAP, or if you really can't then [work around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997039/antidote-for-magic-quotes-gpc).